# Loading NSBundle Plist file to Document Directory

Tags: ios, iphone

I working with Plist file reading and writing data, To work that in device i have moved plist file from NSBundle to Document Directory programatically. And using that plist to write data.  IS this process is correct way , Will Appstore accept this type of approach. Please help me.

Thanks,

Comment: Yes, this is fine as long as the data you save in Documents is important data that can't be replaced automatically.

Comment: no that definition is from before iCloud backup I'd guess

Comment: it is not so much the folder location but the fact that the data is backuped

Comment: @Daij-Djan And app data that can't be automatically replaced should be backed up.

Comment: @rmaddy no .. I didnt respond for a while because I felt this was going getting 'personal. I might tend to not be the best with words :) but.. this isnt about backuping only - this is about whether those docs belong into DOCUMENTS and in that.. they dont belong if they arent user-created / editable - they belong in a custom app support folder. (you dont have to use caches of course)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no. the plist is not user data and shouldn't be backuped but the documents folder is

move it to library/Caches/ (and be prepared to lose it)

OR

create a custom dir in library .. (e.g. app support)

src: https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/index.html
src2: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/ManagingFIlesandDirectories/ManagingFIlesandDirectories.html

Comment: How do you know the plist isn't user data? I see no problem with putting the file in Documents and having the data backed up.

Comment: the plist comes from his bundle and the user doesn't edit it - just got 1 appp rejected for EXACT same thing. Well.. in our case sql database (which contain images,texts,shapes > 'user data')

Comment: if you really wanna backup stuff, separate real user data from 'initial data' and have two files. backup one, one not

Comment: The OP clearly states that the file is for reading and writing. Since it is being written to, it needs to be backed up because the data is irreplacable.

Comment: So is our db. The proper way is to have Two files then